# Can I get my phone back, given some information like model, IMEI, etc?

Tags: lost-phone

I lost my Android. I have no tracker.

Luckily, I do have some inforomation. I know my model, IMEI, last time used, registration date and more. Can anyone offer advice for getting my phone back?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IMEI of the phone it could be possible to track it and find it. The problem is that network operators are very unlikely to do this without a police order, and the police doesn't seems to like hunting lost phones very much (unless you are an important person or politician). I read about a stolen Mac case when the police didn't make too much effort for recovering it even after the [real owner bought them photos of the stealer](http://thisguyhasmymacbook.tumblr.com/).

So, unfortunately, there aren't big chances to get your phone back...

Answer (score 0):

If your phone still has power, you can install and start [androidlost](http://www.androidlost.com) remotely.