# Lost my Android YU Yureka yesterday (12/1/2016)

Tags: lost-phone, android-device-manager, gps-tracking

Is it possible to track a lost phone by IMEI number?

Android Device Manager is active on my mobile.

Will it de-activate if the person who stole does `Factory Reset`?

It has CyanogenMod rom.

Comment: Related: [Tracking Android Phone via IMEI number](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/52099/16575) / [Can I get my phone back, given some information like model, IMEI, etc?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/40721/16575). But Android Device Manager is the best way to go (and do it fast, before the battery runs down or the "finder" factory-resets the device).

Answer (score 0):

You can locate, make ring, or erase your device from the android . [device manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager)

Sign in with your Gmail acount. Then choose your relevant device and choose what action you want. [Google help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491?hl=en)

As far as a factory reset honestly with Google search new security protocol it is supposed to prevent it. That being that if a device is factory reset in order to change google accounts the old account must be entered. So if they cannot sign into your old Gmail account then they cannot change to a new Gmail account. The majority of people will not be able to get around that.